# Git "auto packing" seems to have removed all commits from branch

Tags: git

Just before I committed, I had staged all my changes by using `git ..` (I was in a sub directory) and I had run git status to see the staged changes. Git had staged only the changed files at that point, just as expected.

In the command line, I run `git commit` with a message, get this response:

```
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
[SelectingDate 910641c4] Switching from many visibility animators to one translate animated view. Cuts down time to update list significantly.
 7 files changed, 43 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)
 rename mobile/features/itemLists/CursorItemsCoordinator/{AnimatedVisibilityCursor.native.js => AnimatedTranslatingCursor.native.js} (52%)
```

Not used to seeing the auto packing message, though I've found other articles that could help me get rid of it. Nevertheless, according to his cl response, the changes seem to have been committed.

Then I immediately run `git status` and to my surprise, this is the response:

```
On branch SelectingDate

No commits yet
```

It then lists all files in my repository as being staged.

The files in my repo seem to be updated to their current version, which is good. Does any one know what might have happened that would have removed all commits from my current branch / how to get them back (if possible)?

Here's the command line interaction in full:

```
➜  mobile git:(SelectingDate) ✗ gs
On branch SelectingDate
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    features/itemLists/CursorItemsCoordinator/AnimatedVisibilityCursor.native.js
    modified:   features/itemLists/CursorItemsCoordinator/CursorItemsCoordinator.native.js
    modified:   features/itemLists/CursorItemsCoordinator/interpolaters.native.js
    modified:   features/itemLists/MainListView/MainItemsList.native.js
    modified:   helpers/animatedIndexHelper.native.js
    modified:   ../shared/itemLists/listTypes/plan/PlanItemsContainer.shared.js
    modified:   ../web/src/__test__/native/interpolaters.test.js

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    features/itemLists/CursorItemsCoordinator/AnimatedTranslatingCursor.native.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
➜  mobile git:(SelectingDate) ✗ git add ..
➜  mobile git:(SelectingDate) ✗ gs
On branch SelectingDate
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    renamed:    features/itemLists/CursorItemsCoordinator/AnimatedVisibilityCursor.native.js -> features/itemLists/CursorItemsCoordinator/AnimatedTranslatingCursor.native.js
    modified:   features/itemLists/CursorItemsCoordinator/CursorItemsCoordinator.native.js
    modified:   features/itemLists/CursorItemsCoordinator/interpolaters.native.js
    modified:   features/itemLists/MainListView/MainItemsList.native.js
    modified:   helpers/animatedIndexHelper.native.js
    modified:   ../shared/itemLists/listTypes/plan/PlanItemsContainer.shared.js
    modified:   ../web/src/__test__/native/interpolaters.test.js

➜  mobile git:(SelectingDate) ✗ gc "Switching from many visibility animators to one translate animated view. Cuts down time to update list significantly."
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
[SelectingDate 910641c4] Switching from many visibility animators to one translate animated view. Cuts down time to update list significantly.
 7 files changed, 43 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)
 rename mobile/features/itemLists/CursorItemsCoordinator/{AnimatedVisibilityCursor.native.js => AnimatedTranslatingCursor.native.js} (52%)
➜  mobile git:(SelectingDate) ✗ gs
On branch SelectingDate

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   ../.gitignore
    new file:   ../.prettierignore
    new file:   ../.yarn/install-state.gz
    new file:   ../README.md
    new file:   .eslintrc.json
    new file:   .expo-shared/assets.json
    new file:   .prettierrc.json
    new file:   App.native.js
    new file:   app.json
    new file:   assets/adaptive-icon.png
    new file:   assets/favicon.png
    new file:   assets/fonts/MavenProLight-200.otf
    new file:   assets/fonts/MavenProLight-300.otf
    new file:   assets/fonts/MavenProMedium.otf
    new file:   assets/fonts/maven_pro_bold-webfont.ttf
    new file:   assets/fonts/maven_pro_regular-webfont.ttf
    new file:   assets/icon.png
    new file:   assets/splash.png
    new file:   babel.config.js
    new file:   constants/colors.js
... (and all the rest of the files in my repository)
```

The .git directory is still present at the project root, and is more than 100mb large.

git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)

result of running `git reflog --all`

```
910641c4 (selectingDate) refs/heads/selectingDate@{0}: commit: Switching from many visibility animators to one translate animated view. Cuts down time to update list significantly.
f367a4d0 (refs/stash) refs/stash@{0}: WIP on SelectingDate: 37d06850 Ensures that restoreListener is readded to animatedDateValue when it is updated (and that any old one is removed).
e1437645 refs/stash@{1}: WIP on master: 193f904e Merge pull request #213 from bendelonlee/MobileGraphicCalNotes
f16f4e59 refs/stash@{2}: WIP on selectingDate: 37d06850 Ensures that restoreListener is readded to animatedDateValue when it is updated (and that any old one is removed).
37d06850 refs/heads/selectingDate@{1}: commit: Ensures that restoreListener is readded to animatedDateValue when it is updated (and that any old one is removed).
...
```

Comment: There might be some clues in the output of "git reflog".

Comment: What *exactly* are your `gs` and `gc` aliases, please?

Comment: @Schwern `gs` = `git status`, gc = `git commit -m`

Comment: @IMSoP, running `git reflog` returns `fatal: your current branch 'SelectingDate' does not have any commits yet`

Comment: @BenjaminLee Does `.git/logs/refs/heads/SelectingDate` exist? If so, what's the last few lines? You can also try `git reflog --all` and `git log --graph --decorate --reflog --all` to try and find your missing commit.

Comment: @Shwern in .git/logs/refs/heads/ there's a branch that's /selectingDate.  That is the name of the branch when I created it. The last time I checked it out, I ran `git checkout SelectingDate`. This difference in casing is a likely culprit, thanks for pointing me to look in `/heads`.

I tried running `git checkout selectingDate` results in `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree`

Comment: @Shwern, I put the results of running `git reflog --all` in the question, it wasn't readable in the comments.

Comment: just a guess: are you on a case insensitive filesystem? the reflog output and your status output differ by casing

Comment: @AnthonySottile I'm pretty certain that was the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr Checkout selectingDate.

Here's what happened.

You're on a case-insenstive filesystem. This is important because Git can store branch names as files; `.git/refs/heads/selectingDate` contains the commit ID of your selectingDate branch. At some point you did a `git checkout SelectingDate` which tried to open `.git/refs/heads/SelectingDate` and opened `.git/refs/heads/selectingDate` instead.

This sort of works, but there's problems. While SelectingDate will match files named selectingDate, it won't match it in text such as .git/config which might have configuration for `[branch "selectingDate"]`. Your currently checked out commit is stored in .git/HEAD which now contains `ref: refs/heads/SelectingDate`.

Then `git gc` happens and it packs your references. It deletes all the individual files in .git/refs and writes them in one text file `.git/packed-refs`. Now the branch names are case sensitive! `.git/HEAD` still says you're on SelectingDate. Git tries to return your checkout to "SelectingDate"'s commits, but it can't find a reference to it in `.git/packed-refs` and `.git/refs/heads/selectingDate` is gone. So it thinks it has no commits.

To fix this, checkout selectingDate.

If `git branch` also shows SelectingDate, delete it.

If you accidentally delete both branches don't panic. Branches are just labels. Restore the branch with `git branch selectingDate 910641c4`. 910641c4 being the commit ID of your last commit to selectingDate.

See also

- [Git Internals - Packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles)
- [Git Internals - Git References](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References)

Comment: Before I got your answer, I made a backup copy of the repo, deleted all files, checked out master, then checked out `selectingDate`. This seems to have worked.

Comment: In the back up copy, just to see what would happen, I ran `git reset --hard 910641c4`.  This also worked, by and large. One difference though, in the copy where I `reset`, the head reported by `git log` is: `(HEAD -> SelectingDate, selectingDate)`  whereas the first line in the other copy is `(HEAD -> selectingDate)`

Comment: @Shwern does `(HEAD -> SelectingDate, selectingDate)` seem concerning to you? I'm inclined to put the delete, checkout master, checkout branch method as the accepted answer since `HEAD -> selectingDate)` is less weird... but there's a lot about git I don't know

Comment: @BenjaminLee From some experimenting, `(HEAD -> SelectingDate, selectingDate)` is because your refs have been packed. Instead of files in .git/refs/heads/ branches are now lines in .git/packed-refs. Now they *are* case sensitive. If you look inside you'll see SelectingDate and selectingDate both at the same commit. Just `git branch -d` whichever you do not want.

Comment: I ran git branch -d selectingDate and it seems to have deleted both branches... Not a big deal since it was backed up of course.

Comment: @BenjaminLee I thought SelectingDate was the wrong one. Either way, you can restore with `git branch selectingDate 910641c4`. Branches are just labels.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is, as @asottle guessed, I'm on a case insensitive file system. I had named the branch `selectingDate` but had checked it out at as `SelectingDate`, which shouldn't have succeeded but did. Perhaps during "Auto packing" git moved me to branch 'SelectingDate' which doesn't exist.

If this is your problem, one solution is to make a backup copy of your repo, remove all tracked files from it (otherwise you can't checkout another branch, and you can't run `git stash` because there are no commits), checkout master, then checkout the branch with casing as it was originally known to git, e.g. `selectingDate`. I did this and my latest commit was still there, and I haven't noticed any problems caused by it.

Many thanks to @Shwern.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! It appears Git will checkout case-insensitively because the branch names are just file names. But if the branch name is in a text file it won't match. `git checkout main` will try to open `.git/refs/heads/MAIN` and open `.git/refs/head/main`, but it will not match `[branch "main"]` in .git/config. I sometimes do work on a case-sensitive disk image to avoid these sorts of issues.